# Returning value from select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query string

```
  select a.name, a.address
  from table_main a
  where a.id=3345
```

To this query I am trying to add a.amount if it is null to return zero if not return some value

```
 select a.name, a.addres, isnull(a.amount, 0) else 333
 from table_main a
 where a.id=3345
```

Any ideas how to fix this so that if a.amount is null it returns zero if not than return value i.e 333
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.name, a.addres,
      case when a.amount is null then 0 else 333 end amount 
 from table_main a
 wher a.id=3345
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` statement

```
select a.name, 
       a.addres,
       case when a.amount is null 
            then 0 
            else 333
       end as amount_check
from table_main a
wher a.id = 3345
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (Use Case-When statement)

```
select a.name, a.addres, case when a.amount is NULL then 0 else 333 end as Amount
from table_main a
wher a.id=3345
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround it in a CASE statement

```
SELECT a.NAME,
   a.addres,
   CASE 
      WHEN a.amount IS NULL
         THEN 0
      ELSE 333
   END
FROM table_main a where a.id = 3345
```

Comment: Does the person who downvoted my answer care to leave a comment and explain why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select a.name, a.addres,
case when a.amount is null then 0 else 333 end
from table_main a where a.id=3345
```